# Locally debugging a Reactjs code using firebase cli

Tags: reactjs, firebase, debugging

I'm trying to debug a React app which uses Firebase functions, without having to build it for production

I used create-react-app. 
Inside the app I'm reading some data from Firebase functions.

When I'm debugging using the "yarn start", I can't exeute the Firebase Functions and when I'm using the "firebase serve" I need to specify a folder , "/Build", so I have to build it as for production and it makes the debugging vary hard.

Is there a way to debug the none "production ready" version of the code using firebase serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an Axios "wrapper".
In the case of production, I return the regular Axios.
In case of development, I return an Axios instance with a baseURL of my functions endpoint

```
import Axios from 'axios';
let instance
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    instance = Axios;
} else {
    console.log(Axios);
    instance = Axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://us-central1-blalba-1234.cloudfunctions.net',
        timeout: 2000
    });
}
export default instance;
```

using it like this:

```
import Axios from 'AxiosWrapper';

Axios.get('/api/1234').then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
```